# Finding the maximum area of a rectangular damaged Manuscript in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this image below. How can I find the original area of the manuscript? 
 I used `imfill` and was able to find the area within the boundaries, but I need the maximum area of just the manuscript itself within the image

[image: Damaged Manuscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S5lg.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the bounding box / bounding rectangle to approximate the original area.

Use regionprops to calculate the property BoundingBox.

ConvexHull might help as well but I guess the resulting area would tend to be to small.

http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html